# Can raspberry pi 3b+ run ros noetic

Tags: ros, arduino#ros#raspberry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm try to install ros on my rasp pi 3b+ and my laptop is using ubuntu 20.04 and ros noetic, so I wonder if my rasp pi 3b+ can use ros noetic without any issue about specifications

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386337/can-raspberry-pi-3b+-run-ros-noetic/) by [Uchiwuwu](https://answers.ros.org/users/84587/uchiwuwu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-09-12

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-13**:
Have you looked into Ubuntu Mate 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on what do you want to build on your rpi. Could you at least tell something more in order to estimate whether your rpi could run noetic or not?
Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Ronro](https://answers.ros.org/users/81242/ronro/) with karma: 46 on 2021-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Uchiwuwu](https://answers.ros.org/users/84587/uchiwuwu/) on 2021-09-13**:
I'm planning using lidar sensor to draw a map with ROS gmapping and because pi 3b+ only has 1GB RAM. So I doubt that it would have enough RAM to run ROS and control 18 servos and 6 force sensor, but I don't know how to estimate memory using

**Comment by [Ronro](https://answers.ros.org/users/81242/ronro/) on 2021-09-14**:
I guess the only problem here is gmapping. If gmapping is only executed one time per "cycle" maybe you can try it with rpi 3B+ (probably slow af when gmapping up) but if you want to have gmapping continuously running, you might have to buy a rpi 4 of at least 2 GB of RAM (4 GB better)
I was running ARUCO detection in 3B+ (can´t remember the size of the ram) and it was slow as hell but ARUCO algorithms are unoptimized.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-14**:
Not ideal but opencv detection in ARUCO can run with 2GB RAM with C++ and that should help you with speed.

**Comment by [Ronro](https://answers.ros.org/users/81242/ronro/) on 2021-09-14**:
@osilva Can´t remember the amount of RAM but it really was slow. Can´t either remember if ARUCO was implemented on Python or C++ hahaha

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-16**:\

> I was running ARUCO detection in 3B+ (can´t remember the size of the ram) and it was slow as hell but ARUCO algorithms are unoptimized.

I don't know this statement can help you or not, but you should consider it.

1. If you decrease the size of your video stream to lower pixels.
2. Instead of RGB channels just use black and white.

I think that can saves a lot of raspberry pi resources and can be helpful for Aruco detection.

**Comment by [Ronro](https://answers.ros.org/users/81242/ronro/) on 2021-09-16**:
@Ranjit Kathiriya Thanks for the help but that was not an issue. I have already overcome that.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Noetic on Ras pi 2 (Ubuntu 20.04 server) with no problem.
Because of low capacity of Rasp pi 2, it cannot run SLAM itself. I just use Rasp for data collection then my laptop do SLAM

---

Originally posted by [TuanVo213](https://answers.ros.org/users/84118/tuanvo213/) with karma: 11 on 2021-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1